# updateDrawState is not called in CompoundView

Tags: android, textview

I want to replicate the AnimatedRainbowSpans [Chiuki's talk](http://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/) effect into a compound view

My current code has following structure

```
class Slider extends RelativeLayout{
setText(){}
static propertyAnimator
static class colorSpan
}

Fragment{
// creates view with above compound view
}
```

This doesn't render anything which i find quite quirky

complete code at https://github.com/uddyami/advanced-textview/tree/my-master

Answer (score 0):

Two of your constructors just call `super`, so done of your code is run. Change it to call your own constructor:

```
public RooText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {        
    this(context, null);  // instead of super(context, null);
}

public RooText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {       
    this(context, attrs, 0);  // instead of super(context, attrs, 0);
}
```